# Dynamic $scope DOM elements not ready for plugin initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Quite new to the world of AngularJS and barring a few tutorials and demos I've picked through, this is my first attempt at building something in depth. So apologies if I don't properly explain what's likely a simple question!

I have a controller that looks like:

```
myApp.controller('ShowCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'rest/details/'+ $routeParams.identifier
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.shows = response.data;
      myPlugin.init();

   }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $scope.shows = "something bad happened";
   });
});
```

This makes a GET request to a custom REST interface which makes a call to an external/3rd party api. I then take that api response, assign it to the scope, and loop through it to display the items in my partial .html

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, show) in shows" class="required-element">
  {{ show.title }}
</li>
```

This works GREAT. The scope has the response and I can loop and display the elements as expected.

*The issue arises* with the fact that I'm also using a plugin which seems to get initialized *before* the elements are written to the DOM.

You can see in the code above that the plugin's .init(); is called *just after* assigning the api response to the controller $scope. Therefore, no functionality from the plugin is bound to those elements.

Is there some way to defer my init(); to a time when I can be sure the DOM elements have been written to the page? I've done a bunch of searching around for a solution and it seems like maybe an angular **directive** might be a solution here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[UPDATE] - OK, I've <s>found a couple of solutions so far (one of which is causing me to facepalm). Neither seems like the "best" way though.</s> failed a couple of times

<s>- the easy way. init the plugin via jQuery document.ready(); - this works for some reason and makes me feel silly for how long it took me to try.</s> (nvm, didn't work)

<s>- by moving my $http GET requests to an angular "Factory" with a promise to return. I would load the scope with one, then my plugin with another. Seems like overkill but quite the learning experience.</s>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `$timeout` to your controller and use it like this:

```
myApp.controller('ShowCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'rest/details/'+ $routeParams.identifier
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.shows = response.data;
      $timeout(function() {
           myPlugin.init();
      });
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $scope.shows = "something bad happened";
   });
});
```

This way you will call the `myPlugin.init();` function only after the digest loop has ended and the view is rendered.

Comment: Boom bam! I believe this this is exactly what I was looking for.

I was wrong with my earlier comment too, the document.ready(); didn't actually work.

Comment: @Just2Jays - Just making sure - my answer still works, right?

Comment: sure does! Thanks again!